# Is it necessary to grant an application pool identity a read permission on the web folder?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I always grant application pool identities a write-only permission on the web folder.

However, some people grant them a read-write permission.

The question is

> Is it necessary to grant an application pool identity a read permission on the web folder? Does granting a write permission suffice?

### Edit 1

Up to now, I have not got any problem by granting write-only permission.

Could you give a case where read permission is needed?

### Edit 2

I have a `data.txt` in `App_Data` folder and in my action method I have codes as follows:

```
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.txt")))
        {
            string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            // do more things here.
        }
```

So far so good.

### Edit 3

I have a folder `Content` containing a bunch of pdf files. Users still can download them.

Answer (score 2):

Nice write up here: [Why can I upload a file without IIS Write Permission?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2005/08/20/why-can-i-upload-a-file-without-iis-write-permission.aspx)

> - "Read" access controls whether the HTTP GET verb is allowed.
> - "Write" access controls whether HTTP PUT verb is allowed.

Comment: I am using IIS 7.5. I think the given link no longer matches my question. IIS Manager gives us the same permission settings dialog as what we obtain by right-click a folder and selecting Properties.

Comment: My answer is probably not relevant then, I added the IIS 7.5 tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you need Read access to get the web.config file.

Depends on your security.

Just had to grant a AppPool identity Read access to it could grab a web.config.  Not positive if I've ever had to do this in the past but granting read access fixed my problem.

Never had to set write before.